# imported css files are not compiled into application.css file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a style.scss file where i have imported bunch of other files like

```
@import url(asset-path('bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('ionicons/css/ionicons.min.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('owl-carousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('owl-carousel/assets/owl.theme.default.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('owl-carousel/assets/carousel.min.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.scss'));
@import url(asset-path('magicsuggest/magicsuggest-min.scss'));
```

these files are located under vendor/ directory.

Looking at the network tab in production mode, the server makes request to each an every of those imported files from the scss files instead of compiling them under on file.

I am also using sass rails gem. Is there anything I am not understanding about the rails assets pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The confusion comes from the fact that SASS overrides the @import directive in a way.

In your case the pure [CSS' @import directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) is used since your are passing `url(..`, which as you noticed makes HTTP request for every file.

In order to use the SASS' version of @import (which will import and combine the contents), you need to pass the files in quotes:

```
...  
@import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss';
...
```

Here's a detailed explanation about [SASS' @import](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import)

Answer (score 0):

Your master css file is done through `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css` file.

For example :

```
*= require navbars.css.scss
*= require footer.css.scss
*= require cookiewarning.css.scss
*= require_self
```

The above code will include in the `application.css` master file all of the mentionned css files, whether they are located in `app/assets` `app/lib` or `app\vendor`.

You master file is called in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>  
<%= yield(:headcss) %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag params[:controller], media: 'all' %>
```

As you can see I have a separate file for the current controller. And also a `yield` tag for extra CSS I would like to add when needed.

Also one note about your files: SASS is a preprocessor of CSS. It is better to name your files `whatever.css.scss` than `whatever.scss`. I got some problems getting the SASS helpers work properly because of this: [Sass rails seems to generate a different logical path than in manifest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52102473/sass-rails-seems-to-generate-a-different-logical-path-than-in-manifest)